# How to call VBScript from cmd.exe *and* pass parameters

Tags: vbscript, shortcut

I have a VBScript that I want to launch by dragging and dropping files onto a shortcut to it. At the moment the script does nothing except report how many parameters it receives and echo the first.

If I define the shortcut as:

```
"C:\Users\me\Documents\working\my_script.vbs" "param 1"
```

then, upon launch, it tells me I have one parameter and it is "param 1" exactly as you would expect. However, if I drag and drop a file onto the shortcut, I still only get one parameter and that is the path to the dropped file.

How do I get two parameters (whatever is coded into the link) and the drag-drop filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your shortcut properties, and instead of directly link to the .vbs file, use

```
WScript.exe "C:\Users\me\Documents\working\my_script.vbs" "param 1"
```

Now, the correct number of arguments is retrieved

Comment: +1, This is the only way I can get *any* shortcut args to work since upgrading from XP to Windows 7.

Comment: Thank-you, that worked perfectly. In fact I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't try that for myself, first!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my args loop:

```
Set oArgs = Wscript.Arguments

Dim aArgs()
ReDim aArgs(oArgs.Count)
x = 0
Do Until x = oArgs.Count
  aArgs(x) = oArgs(x)
  x=x+1
Loop
```

Now you can reference your arguments by doing something like this:

```
Wscript.Echo aArgs(0)
```

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by copying the WScript.Arguments collection? Are you aware of the difference between .Count and UBound()? How does this help the OT who looses the fixed argument when dropping a file?

Comment: Well after you suck them out of the Arguments collection you can group the appropriately and don't necessarily have to delimit them by the space character. So you could group "/user bob" into one array variable.